# Tratar undefined behavior de leitura de código binário como diferentes tipos

Tags: c++, union

Dizem que este código de função inline apresenta "undefined behavior", quer seja por códigos binários de mesmo significado em float e diferentes em outros tipos, seja porque a ordem de armazenamento e uso do dado pode mudar com a otimização e também mudar os resultados, etc.

```
union DWord {
    char32_t c ;
    signed __int32 si ;
    unsigned __int32 ui ;
    float f ;
} ;

inline int FloatToInt32( float f ){
    DWord dw ;
    dw.f = f ;
    return dw.si ;
}
```

Essa é realmente uma maneira inadequada de implementar leituras de código binário significando valores de diversos tipos? Há uma maneira oficialmente aceita de implementar a union (ou struct/class) DWord de maneira que não ocorram prejuízos de desempenho e conserte comportamento indefinido onde DWord é usada?

Mais uma coisa. Há uma maneira padronizada de identificar UBs e repará-los? Existe alguma fonte que diga que comportamentos são indefinidos e que códigos alternativos têm comportamentos definidos?

Comment: Provavelmente é melhor você quebrar em múltiplas questões.
Quanto a detectar undefined behavior, o compilador clang possui alguns "sanitizers" e um deles é justamente detectar undefined behavior. Basta compilar por exemplo como `clang input.c -fsanitize=undefined`